# How to conect to local postgres database using pgadmin4 docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, pgadmin-4

In my pc I have postgressql running locally on port 5432, I am also running a docker container with pgadmin4. I am trying to use that docker pgadmin4 to manage the local postgres database but I am getting "could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?"
I have already done this to allow conections to postgres

I edited the PostgreSQL client authentication configuration file pg_hba.conf and add the following at the end:

host all all all md5

I edited the PostgreSQL configuration file postgresql.conf file and replaced this line

listen_address='127.0.0.1'

with:

listen_addresses = '*'

But I cannot conect to the postgres local database from pgadmin4
[image: I tried to connect from pgadmin4 with these options]

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `host.docker.internal` in the hostname, and `5432` in port, it should point to your Postgres running on your host